# Zend Framework InArray validator array syntax

Tags: zend-framework, zend-validate

My goal is to validate parameters passed in the URL, so I created a validate method that has a list of validators to run, like so:

```
$validators = array(
        'number' => array(
            'digits',
            'presence' => 'required',
            'messages' => array(
                "%value%' is not a valid number.",
            ),
        ),
        'country' => array(
            'presence' => 'required',
            'InArray' => array('haystack' => array('USA', 'CAN', 'AUS', 'JPN')),
            'messages' => array(
                "'%value%' is not a valid country code.",
            ),
        ),
        // etc. 
);

$valid = new Zend_Filter_Input(array(), $validators, $data);
return $valid->isValid()
```

The issue is that the 'InArray' validator does nothing. It doesn't raise any errors, it just doesn't work.  I assume that I'm getting the syntax wrong.

What is the correct syntax for the 'InArray' validator?

Comment: What are you passing those validators to?  `haystack` should probably be its own index like `messages` is, not an array element on the `InArray` key.

Comment: I updated the question for clarity. Are you saying that 'InArray' would be declared like 'digits', with 'haystack' as a separate index? [Ok, that doesn't work. It results in a Missing argument for Zend_Validate_InArray]

Comment: See my answer, I thought you may have been trying to pass the array to Zend_Form which would accept a haystack parameter although not in the format provided above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To pass additional rules and properties to validators to be used with `Zend_Filter_Input`, create a concrete instance of the object and set it as your validator like this:

```
    $validators = array(
            'number' => array(
                    'digits',
                    'presence' => 'required',
                    'messages' => array(
                            "%value%' is not a valid number.",
                    ),
            ),
            'country' => array(
                    new Zend_Validate_InArray(
                        array('haystack' => array('USA', 'CAN', 'AUS', 'JPN'))
                    ),
                    'presence' => 'required',
                    'messages' => array(
                            "'%value%' is not a valid country code.",
                    ),
            ),
            // etc.
    );
```

The reason you have to do it like this is because there are no filter [metacommands](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.filter.input.html#zend.filter.input.metacommands) for setting the haystack when using the `InArray` validator.  There are some basic metacommands that apply to many validators, but haystack is not one of them.

To specify the haystack, create a new `Zend_Validate_InArray` object directly with the require options and pass that validator to the array of validators given to `Zend_Filter_Input`.